# MATLAB get date from week number and year

Tags: matlab, date

In Matlab 2016a, I have a vector of week numbers:

```
weekNum = [20 21 22 23];
```

Is there a way to convert the week numbers to their respective dates in 2018 starting on Sunday?

Comment: The first week is usually defined as the week that includes January 1st, and can include days from the previous year. This means you could end up with a date in 2017 for week 1. Is that okay?

Comment: Yes that works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using the functions [`days`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/days.html) and [`weekday`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/weekday.html). Starting with the first day of the year, you can subtract days to find the previous Sunday (if it isn't Sunday already), then multiply your vector `weekNum` by 7 to add offsets to that date for each desired week:

```
weekNum = [20 21 22 23];
t = datetime(2018, 1, 1, 'Format', 'dd-MMMM-yyyy');  % First day of the year
t = t - days(weekday(t)-1) + days((weekNum-1).*7);
```

And this gives you the following array of Sunday datetimes:

```
t = 

  1×4 datetime array

   13-May-2018    20-May-2018    27-May-2018    03-June-2018
```

And you can confirm it works using [`week`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/week.html):

```
>> week(t)

ans =

    20    21    22    23  % Same as weekNum
```

**NOTE:** The first week is usually defined as the week that includes January 1st, and can include days from the previous year. This means you could end up with a date in 2017 for a Sunday in week 1.

Comment: Would this work for any year besides 2018, or would I need to change anything? Thanks.

Comment: @pseudorandom: It should work for any year. Just change the year argument for the first day. Everything else stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
% 1st day of year
D = datetime(2018,1,1);
% datetime objects representing the Sunday of the specified weeks
Dt = D + (20:23)*7-7-(weekday(D)-1);
```

This assumes that week 1 is defined to be the first week for which at least one day is in 2018.  If you use a different definition, adjust your indexes accordingly.

Comment: Setting the format of `datetime` to `'dd-MMMM-yyyy eee'` or just `'dd-MMMM-yyyy'` may make it look nicer

Answer (score 1):

What I love about Matlab is that, sometimes, you can delegate computational tasks to the underlying Java framework, if you know it a little bit:

```
year = 2018;
week = [20 21 22 23];
dow = 1;

sep = repmat('-',4,1);
chain = [repmat(num2str(year),4,1) sep num2str(week.','%d') sep repmat(num2str(dow),4,1)];

df = java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-w-u');

for i = 1:4
    date = 719529 + (df.parse(chain(i,:)).getTime() / 1000 / 3600 / 24);
    disp(datestr(date,'dd-mm-yyyy'));
end
```

Output:

```
13-05-2018
20-05-2018
27-05-2018
03-06-2018
```